# How to set height (in multiples of *) of a WPF grid cell programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have to set height of a CELL inside WPF Grid programmatically, based on values in a List or ObservableCollection. Mind that I want to set height of a CELL not ROW.

Note that the grid is generated programmatically

```
Grid myGrid = new Grid();

ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

// Define the Rows
RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef4 = new RowDefinition();
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef4);
```

Each cell of the grid contains either textboxes or borders as shown below.

```
            ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
            Border b = new Border();
            b.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
            b.Padding = new Thickness(10);
            TextBlock txt3 = new TextBlock();
            txt3.Text = "Hello";
            txt3.FontSize = 12;
            txt3.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            txt3.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            txt3.Margin = new Thickness(2);


            Grid.SetColumn(txt3,2);                            
            b.Child = txt3;
            //Grid.SetColumn(txt3, 2);                
            //Grid.SetRowSpan (txt3,2);
            //myGrid.Children.Add(txt3);
            Grid.SetColumn(b, 2);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(b, 2);               
            myGrid.Children.Add(b);
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post some code on how you're generating the grid?

Comment: @tencntraze I have generated the grid as shown in the examples at below. Added the code in the question.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.90).aspx#feedback

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML is for. Use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: @HighCore I need to create rows and columns dynamically dependening on user input. Where should I write above code? In ViewModel or code file? I am using PRISM architecture.

Comment: @HighCore BTW its a big mesh with 50 rows and 20 columns

Comment: @user2951819 post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore I can't as its confidential.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense. How could you have a cell with a different height than the row?  That just won't work.

You should just set the height on the RowDefinition for the row of that cell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to note, that setting a cell height more than row, will lead to cell cut off.

The second thing is that, there are no cell's, imagine Grid as a 2 dimensional array - you can set only content - if content overflows there are two possible ways - cell's content will be cut off or RowHeight will be increased based on the highest content in a row - the same for Columns.

Maybe if you would provide us with graphical example of what you are filling into the table, and why should cell's height increase, we would help you to find appropriate solution.

But now, you are going a wrong way...